# ASP.NET JavaScript Function Call code-behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Question updated.

Reference:
http://www.startuppirates.org/blog/gritter/

Following is working fine, when click on the html link "Add Regular" it shows the notification so related .js and .css is working.

HTML Link

```
<a href="#" id="add-regular">Add regular notification</a>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#add-regular').click(function () {

        var unique_id = $.gritter.add({
            // (string | mandatory) the heading of the notification
            title: 'This is a regular notice!',
            // (string | mandatory) the text inside the notification
            text: 'This will fade out after a certain amount of time.',
            // (string | optional) the image to display on the left
            image: '/content/gritter/images/success.png',
            // (bool | optional) if you want it to fade out on its own or just sit there
            sticky: false,
            // (int | optional) the time you want it to be alive for before fading out
            time: '',
            class_name: 'gritter-info'
        });
        return false;
    });

</script>
```

I have modified above JS into a function with parameters, and I'm trying to call it to show the notification from code-behind (asp.net / web-forms) but it is not working !

Codebehind

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "return", "stickyalert('Property Upload', 'property data uploaded successfully', 0, 'success');", True)
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function stickyalert(title, text, sticky, success) {
        var unique_id = $.gritter.add({
            // (string | mandatory) the heading of the notification
            title: title,
            // (string | mandatory) the text inside the notification
            text: text,
            // (string | optional) the image to display on the left
            image: '/content/gritter/images/success.png',
            // (bool | optional) if you want it to fade out on its own or just sit there
            sticky: sticky,
            // (int | optional) the time you want it to be alive for before fading out
            time: '5000',
            // (string | optional) the class name you want to apply to that specific message
            class_name: 'gritter-info'
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET page? If so, are you using Web Forms or MVC?

Comment: You need to do modifications in your understanding of how web applications work. When server-side code executes it does so hundreds of thousands :) kilometers away from user's browser, where the above function is defined and may run. All server-side code can do is to send a response to the browser (a full page, part of the page or data) and hope that javascript will run in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to put your functionality inside it's own function. Then, in addition to calling this function from your click event, render a script in your page to call the function when it loads utilizing the jquery api.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunc() {
        $.gritter.add({
            // (string | mandatory) the heading of the notification
            title: 'This is a regular notice!',
            // (string | mandatory) the text inside the notification
            text: 'This will fade out after a certain amount of time.',
            // (string | optional) the image to display on the left
            image: '/content/gritter/images/success.png',
            // (bool | optional) if you want it to fade out on its own or just sit there
            sticky: false,
            // (int | optional) the time you want it to be alive for before fading out
            time: '',
            class_name: 'gritter-info'
        });
    }

    //Call it when the page loads
    $(document).ready(function() {
        myFunc();
    });

    //Call it on the click event
    $('#add-regular').click(function () {
        myFunc();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I need to call it from code-behind after form submit :)

Comment: After form submit? You can't. Please update your question.

Comment: @GeoConcepts, then you need to put that in the question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion,I need to call this function from code-behind to display alert after sending data to SQL